# Why am I not able to start a scrapy shell?

Tags: python, scrapy

I tried to run a scrapy shell, but my computer can't find it:

```
C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\Scrapy_Project>scrapy shell
'scrapy' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Do you have any idea where to start?

Comment: You probably need to add scrapy's folder to your Windows PATH environment variable

Answer (score 0):

Try to make your own virtual environment and install packeges in it include the scrapy.